# How to add fields in JWT token in C#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt, console-application

I want to create a sample console app to generate a JWT token of following format. I have created a simple console app to generate JWT but bit stuck on how to add all required fields into to.
Below is my sample console app code.

```
Console.WriteLine("");
string key = "dummykey";
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var credentials = new SigningCredentials
                  (securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);

//Some dummy PayLoad
var payload = new JwtPayload
           {
               { "firstname ", "lastname "},
               { "scope", "read,write"},
           };

var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var tokenString = handler.WriteToken(secToken);

Console.WriteLine("JWT Token is : ");
Console.WriteLine(tokenString);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Above code generating a JWT with below format.

```
HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
PAYLOAD:DATA

{
  "firstname ": "lastname ",
  "scope": "read,write"
}
VERIFY SIGNATURE

HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
)
```

I want it as below.

```
{
"schema":"value",
"majver":1,
"minver":0,
"sub":"value",
"scope":"read,write",
"iss":"value",
"exp":date,
"nbf":date,
"iat":date,
"jti":"value",
"emp_id":"value",
"act":
   {
      "typ":"value",
      "sub":"value"
   }
}
```

Comment: You could use constructor that accepts claims, and add all you need as custom claims, it will be added to token as properties

Comment: @Vitaly I am new in this. Can you pls help with sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example, just add payload to claims and headers to Header

```
public string GetToken(int tokenValidPeriod, string kid = null)
    {
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            audience: "<your audience>",
            issuer: "<your issuer>",
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(tokenValidPeriod),
            notBefore: DateTime.Now,                
            //payload
            claims: new Claim[]
            { 
                //custom name
                new Claim("somekey", "somevalue"), 
                //registered names
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "somevalue"),                     
            },
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your long key here")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
        
        //Headers
        if (kid != null)
            token.Header.Add(JwtHeaderParameterNames.Kid, kid);
        
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```